# GoogleGlass : Add image in background : unsupported image scheme: http

Tags: android, uri, google-glass, google-gdk

I have a problem when i try to set an image URL on a `Card`.

Here is the error log : `unsupported image scheme: http`

```
01-16 14:11:50.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 14:11:50.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2851):
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported image scheme: http
01-16 14:11:50.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2851):     at
com.google.android.glass.app.Card.addImage(Card.java:178)
01-16 14:11:50.188: E/AndroidRuntime(2851):     at
com.example.cupofnewsglass.MainActivity.processFinish(MainActivity.java:112)
```

Here is my code :

```
// Get img of article, it return an string like : http://img.
String imgUrl = articles.get(i).getImage();
// Get Publication Date
String pubDate = createDateForGlass(articles.get(i).getPubDate());
// Convert imgUrl to an Uri
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(imgUrl);
// Set main text in card
card.setText(title + " ago");
// Set Footer text in card
card.setFootnote(pubDate);
// Image will be in Fullscreen mode
card.setImageLayout(Card.ImageLayout.FULL);
// Set background image in card
card.addImage(imgUri);
```

Comment: `card.addImage(R.Drawable.somefilename);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working as intended, the only supported schemes for the Card builder class are `file` and `android.resource`.

This [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=299) is tracking support for web images in the Card builder class.

Comment: Ohh so bad ! How can i do for setting my image into the card ?